# Issue in styling Material UI CardHeader component's text

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How can I use CardHeader props **title** & **titleTypographyProps** to play around look and feel of Header Text

Material UI 
Docs: [Api Doc](https://material-ui.com/api/card-header/)

Sample Sandbox: [Here you can look at code](https://codesandbox.io/s/x7696qp2z)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`XXXTypographyProps` is forwarded to `Typography` of `XXX` (header, subheader, etc) component element.

For example:

```
titleTypographyProps={{align:"right"}}
```

Will align header to the right.

Check documentation of the [Typography component](https://material-ui.com/api/typography/) for full properties list.